# SQL server language media doesn't support the language of the OS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

While trying to install SQL server 2012, I get the error: "SQL server language media doesn't support the language of the OS"

I've downloaded the SQL server 2012 in English language only (2 times to make sure due to this silly feature/bug) and the Format dropdown in Control Panel Regional Settings is English only.

Attached is the error that I get:

[image]

I already followed this link: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/556958/sql-server-setup-media-does-not-support-the-language-of-the-os

My Windows Server 2012 is a fresh install. No DB has ever been installed. Please suggest what should I do? Should I download the whole 5 Gbs 3rd time or any better option? Thanks Microsoft!

Comment: Kindly provide the Server Hardware ( Processor ) and software ( OS,SQL versions details so that i can try to help you in solving this issue.

Comment: Sippy at Microsoft and epic user failure for not installing a matching operating System? And no, repeating senseless Actions does never solve the Problem.

Comment: @TomTom: Well, it worked in this case :). What did you mean by not installing a matching OS? Should Windows Server 2012 work with SQL server 2012? I installed from a different source and it worked. However, now I have a different issue as shown in my post: http://serverfault.com/questions/464272/sql-server-2012-setup-hangs-no-error-no-success

Comment: @TCM: If you've already solved the problem, feel free to post your solution as an answer.  It will help everyone who sees this later, and you may get rep for it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about database and could be better in that SE

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about 